# Are these apple saplings turning yellow due to autumn or to a virus

Tags: diseases, leaves, fruit-trees, tree-care, apples

So these are 4 year old saplings. They didn’t loose leaves when I began growing them, I thinks it's due to being inside all the time. I just want to make sure, if they're losing leaves due to winter or do they have some sort of disease?

[image: Three pots, one with small sapling and one with a larger sapling, both with yellow and green leaves]
[image: A sapling with 6 yellow and 4 green leaves in a garage]

Comment: pictures please and your location

Comment: Sorry have the picture also location: seattle area

Comment: That’s pretty much impossible to say from this photo. *If* there’s virus damage, we’d need close-ups of the leaves and a good focus to have at least chance of a qualified answer.

Comment: I'm going with overwatering. Slow down for the Winter.

Comment: You do know that apples raised from seed are not guaranteed to produce the same kind of fruit as the parent?  Or did you buy these as larger plants?  Were they really grown inside for four years?

Comment: For a 4 year old tree, it is fairly clear these should have been planted outside 3 years ago. Depending on the weather in Seattle, might I suggest you put them outside in soil asap and wrap some mulch around the base but not touching the stem. 

Very few trees grow successfully indoors, and fruit trees are very specifically for outdoors.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question will depend on the time of year (in this case november) and your region.

For many regions in North America and northern Europe, november is a normal time for trees to start changing into autumn colors. Yellow leafs are a very normal autumn color for an apple, but I've also seen some apple trees show some red leafs.

The difficulty by going with the picture alone is that yellow leafs can also be caused by overwatering or underwatering (although less likely). If the timing is off for your tree to start showing autumn colors, you likely are overwatering it.

Lastly, I would say it's unlikely that this is caused by any kind of disease. Leaf decoloring can be a sign for either a pest or fungi, but in the case of a pest you would generally see other kinds of damage to the leafs, and in case of fungi you would generally see other kinds of decoloring or patterns.

[image: yellow leaf of apple tree in autumn]
*Normal autumn leaf color for an apple tree*